# How can i get the group id from facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How can i get the group id from facebook API

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // optionnal

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }

if (isset($accessToken)) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // validating the access token
    try {
        $request = $fb->get('/me');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
            unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/', $permissions);
            echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
            exit;
        }
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/'</script>";
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // priting basic info about user on the screen
    print_r($profile);

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/', $permissions);
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
}
```

I had codes wherein i am getting 
Array ( [name] => xxxx [first_name] => xxxx [last_name] => xxxx [email] => xxxx [id] =>  xxxxx)

Now I want group ids how can it possible please assist

Answer (score 3):

How to get a list of all the groups you manage is explained very well in the docs, including example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/

You need to authorize with the `user_managed_groups` permisssion and call the **`/me/groups`** endpoint. Do not use the User ID for that endpoint, just use `/me` - it points to the current User anyway:

```
$groups_request = $fb->get('/me/groups');
$groups = $groups_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```

**Be aware that you can only get groups you manage, you can NOT get access to groups you are just a member of.** The `user_groups` permission to get ALL groups has been removed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4 (search for "90-day deprecations")

Answer (score 0):

To access the groups of a user, you need to use the [User Groups endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/)

To read the Facebook groups of a user you need to do yet another API call with:

```
/{user-id}/groups
```

Since you've retrieved the ID in your "/me" call, you're almost there.

You can change your code slightly for this:

```
$profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
$profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();

$groups_request = $fb->get("{$profile['id']}/groups");
$groups = $groups_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
```